# Confused about the Arrow Category

Tags: category-theory

If we use the definition of the Arrow category and the notation from [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/arrow-categories).

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>h>> C \\
@VVfV @VVgV \\
B @>k>> D 
\end{CD}
$$

I think I can understand how the object $f$ from the $C^2$ category gets transformed using $h$ and $k$ into object $g$ if the starting category is just a directed graph (is quiver the correct name?). One just takes $h(A)$ as start and $k(B)$ as the end of the new arrow $g$.

But I'm confused when we start from the $\mathsf{Set}$ category. That is, if in our $C^2$ category the objects are functions. In particular, I don't see a way how construct the function $g\colon C \to D$ from only $f\colon A \to B,\ h\colon A \to C$ and $k\colon B \to D$? None of $f,g,h$ have $C$ as their domain, so there must be something else? Or have I misunderstood the types of $h,k$?

Comment: You don't have to construct function $g$. You want to describe $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C^2}(f,g)$ for given morphisms $f$ and $g$.

Comment: You should look into the construction of a function category. This is just a special case of a function category, but it might be easier to understand in the more general setting rather than the specific setting you're interested in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your mistake is trying to think of morphisms as transformations; morphisms in this category are simply commutative squares; they don't have to "do" anything, aside from satisfy the algebraic properties of a category.

Also, the pair $(h,k)$ is not necessarily sufficient to uniquely identify a morphism in this category: you may need more. e.g. the additional context that we are to construe $(h,k)$ as a morphism from $f$ to $g$.

On this point, an analogy may help; many people take "function" to mean its graph: a set of ordered pairs that satisfies the "vertical line test". If you do this, then specifying a function is not enough to uniquely identify a morphism of $\mathbf{Set}$. If you construe functions as morphisms, you can compute the domains and products of said morphisms using just the functions, but you can't determine the codomains of the morphisms from just the function.

Comment: The morphisms are simply pairs $(h,k)$ that make the given square commute. I have tried to motivate the reason for this definition in my answer.

Comment: @Chilango: As I said, a pair $(h,k)$ is enough to identify a "morphism from $f$ to $g$"; it is *not* enough to identify a "morphism".

Comment: Yes. I was in fact agreeing with your comment and only meant to say that the condition on the pair $(h,k)$ is motivated by considering $C^{2}$ to be a category of functors: $2\to C$ so that the condition on arrows is only a naturality square in disguise.

Comment: @chilangoincomprendido So, the thing is that this would be a functor category only if h and k are the same, and hence a functor… or did I get something wrong? I'm just asking because I've seen also that this category is similar to the functor one only *[up to equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category)*

Comment: The first line clarifies things. A category need only satisfy its axioms; one can check that the given definition for the arrow category does indeed satisfy these axioms.

Answer (score 6):

$C^{2}$ has objects that are arrows $f:a\to b$ of $C$.

A morphism $\phi :f\to g$ is a pair $(h,k)$ such that $k\circ f=g\circ h$

$\tag 1 \begin{matrix}
\operatorname a & \xrightarrow{{f}} & \operatorname b \\
\left\downarrow h\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow k\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
\operatorname c&  \xrightarrow{g} & \operatorname d
\end{matrix}$

You can check that this gives a bonafide category.

But the notation $C^{2}$ tells us why the category, in some sense, must be defined as it is:

A naive way of looking at this would be to say that $C^{2}$ has objects that are $\textbf {functors}$  $F:2\to C$ where $2=\left \{ \bullet, \bullet \bullet \right \}$ is the category with two distinct objects and exactly one arrow $*:\bullet \to \bullet  \bullet $

$F$ will then be specified by its action on $\bullet $ and $\bullet \bullet $:

$F(\bullet )=a$ and $F(\bullet \bullet)=b$

and its action on $*$:

$F(*):F(\bullet )\to F(\bullet \bullet)$ which is just an arrow $a\overset{f}{\rightarrow} b$.

Now consider two objects (functors), $F$ and $G$, in $C^{2}$.

An arrow $\tau :F\to G$ will be a natural transformation of the functors $F$ and $G$, and is specified by its components, $\tau _{\bullet}$ and $\tau _{\bullet \bullet}$ so in fact $\tau $ is a pair $(\tau _{\bullet}, \tau _{\bullet \bullet})$.

The corresponding naturality square is then

$\tag 2 \begin{matrix}
\operatorname F(\bullet ) & \xrightarrow{{F(*)}} & \operatorname F(\bullet \bullet )  \\
\left\downarrow \tau _{\bullet}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow \tau _{\bullet \bullet}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
\operatorname G(\bullet )&  \xrightarrow{G(*)} & \operatorname G(\bullet \bullet )
\end{matrix}$.

Now, to finish, set $(\tau _{\bullet}, \tau _{\bullet \bullet})=(h,k)$ and recall that $F(*)=f$ and $G(*)=g$ to see that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same.

We conclude that our original definition of the arrows in $C^{2}$ is the right one.

Comment: I think you ought to define a morphism literally as (1) and not simply as (h,k). Otherwise it is not a category as Hom (f,g)'s aren't disjoint.